# How to dig through "rough hewn diorite wall"

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I've built an up/down stairs on layer 3, and now I want to dig to layer 4. However, layer 4 reports `rough hewn diorite wall` on the same squares that the up/down stairs occupy in layer 3.

I cannot build any stairs on it since it says 'blocked'. I have tried placing stairs on different areas in layer 3, but no one will dig to layer 4. How do I break through?

Comment: Usually if something is saying "bocked", it's not because of the material type you're trying to dig through.  It's something before that, like your only miner unable to get to it, or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. I'm not supposed to attempt to build a up/down stairs on level 4. There is a special dig command that will dig the floors first: `d`->`i`